# Constrain multiple UIViews around centered UIView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to learn auto-layout/constraints but for the life of me I cannot figure out a solution to my problem. I have multiple buttons surrounding a 'main' button. I would like the layout to remain the same and the buttons to auto resize depending on the device AND to remain in the center of the superview. I have been reading and trying and have yet to get anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

At the moment I am not worried about landscape view but if anyone would like to elaborate that would be great.

Any references I could read or videos would be excellent as well.

Thank you kindly

**Example Layout:**

[image]

Comment: I think you need to do *at least* two things. (1) Work through the `centerXanchor` and `centerYanchor` layout. This will give you the "multiple buttons surrounding a main one" piece. (2) Once you have that nailed, work with the `heightAnchor` and `widthAnchor` constraints. Remember, you can use both *constants* and *multiples*. Remember, you can also add `layoutGuides` instead of invisible views for spacing. THE MAIN THING (at least IMHO): Work through the "centered layout" concept first and *then* work on the sizing.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer some advice.

1. Firstly, all your views and buttons should have proportional widths and heights relative to the screen size of the device you're using so it will look decent across different devices.
2. Secondly, apart from the width and height constraints, your middle "main" button will also have a centerX to your `UIViewControllers's` view as well as a center Y so you can keep it pinned to the middle. This is important because the other 6 buttons will be pinned relative to this main button.
3. Let's start with the other buttons, specifically the one above the main button and the one below the main button. These two buttons also have width and height constraints. Now, horizontally, you have two options - since these guys are always in the middle of the screen, you can align their centerX's to the main button, or to the UIViewController's view itself - it doesn't matter as long as it's in the middle. Lastly, we have to consider the vertical distance from the main button. These distances should be proportional to the total height of the screen so it will look good across all devices. You'll be adding a constraint from the bottom of the top button to the top of the middle button. For the bottom button, you'll be adding a constraint from the top of the bottom button to the bottom of the middle button.
4. Now for the other 4 buttons, apart from the height and width constraints that they will have, you should constrain the horizontal constraints to the top and bottom middle buttons, and then constrain vertically to the main button.

Comment: Interesting. I commented what seems like the *exact* opposite! I'd do the "centered" layout first - maybe with spacing (which I didn't mention) - before doing the height/width after that. Do you agree that you need to **begin** with a centered "main button" before anything else? (Your third point suggests otherwise.) If not, then how would you proceed to layout the *very* first button that everything else is laid out against?